# How to install faiss on Windows Pycharm

Tags: python, pip

I want to install Faiss on my project by Pycharm but I receive the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement faiss (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for faiss.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `faiss` package on PyPi is, according to [the description](https://pypi.org/project/faiss/), an *Unofficial prebuilt binary for Linux and MacOS*. It seems that there are actually multiple unofficial packages for this on PyPi, a few are mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/issues/170).

You can find the official installation instructions for Faiss [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Comment: To make it run I should switch to the Linux ?

Comment: @AzlaanZubair The unofficial `faiss` PyPi package will only run on Linux or macOS, so if you want to use that one specifically, you do indeed need to be on one of the two.

Comment: Official Installation method is "conda install faiss-cpu -c pytorch", but when i run this command it says: 

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: 
-faiss-cpu

Comment: It looks like it's available on macOS and Linux only: https://anaconda.org/pytorch/faiss-cpu

Comment: so finally i've to switch to Ubuntu. can i use same project on ubuntu or i need to make new envirnoment for ubuntu ?

Comment: @AzlaanZubair _can i use same project on ubuntu_ What project? Yes, you should make a new environment. It's best to keep each question on SO focused, if you're having more issues open a new one.